# assert handling standard/platfform dependence

Tags: c++, standards, assert

I am using asserts in my program, and reaching production phase.

According to 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/

> disable all of them for the production version by simply including a
>   line like:
>
> ```
> #define NDEBUG
> ```

However, my Ubuntu C++ compiler said:

> `NDEBUG` redefined [enabled by default]

And really,

```
#undef NDEBUG
```

does what I want. How much can I rely on this behavor to switch asserts on/off in config file, in case of a multi-platform config file?

Comment: Where are you defining `NDEBUG`? If in a header file, it may be from a multiple inclusion (or some files may already have this defined). Look for the exact location (file, line) where this warning appears. It would be best to pass it directly to the compiler (e.g. for `g++` it would be `-DNDEBUG`), in this way you can ensure all files from the project will have it defined.

Comment: `#undef NDEBUG` doesn't help - it may get rid of the warnings, but all the asserts are still active.

Comment: I used the define "at the beginning of the code, before the inclusion of <assert.h>" in main.cpp, as advised by cplusplus, because assert(0) was inactive. The compiler said "enabled by default", and really it is the case. #undef NDEBUG did solve the problem, made assert() active.